# Angular using bsdatepicker posting date 1 day back to asp.net core application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.1, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using Angular6 and bsdatepicker to capture date, back end application is Asp.Net core 2.1 api.

When I look at the database for the entered data I get date one day back.

So, posted data from api using postman to see if API is having any problem but the date from api is getting perfectly fine.

Even at Angular side, console shows correct date.

Here is the code I am using for Angular:

```
console.log(std.DateofBirth);
    let d = new Date(std.DateofBirth);
    console.log(d);
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset());
    std.DateofBirth = d;
    console.log(d);
```

And here is the log:

Wed Feb 22 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
16.6378184bcce0220254d5.js:1 Wed Feb 22 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
16.6378184bcce0220254d5.js:1 Tue Feb 21 2012 18:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Please note I tried solution for this post on Git:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2628

For IST I can add one day but not really sure for all the timezone. Overall I suspect there is some playaround with timezones or I just need vare date no time. How can I solve this.

Comment: did you find any solutions?